# query for lat long not returning any results mysql

Tags: php, mysql, geocoding

I have this table.

wppl_friends_locator

The table have  columns  named

lat float(10,6)

long float(10,6)

These columns have lat and long saved of entries, now i am trying to get results within radius of 30 miles from a given lat,long.

Sql does not return any results for some reasons which i am unable to figure out, below is the sql

```
SELECT
    member_id,
    (3959 * ACOS(
        COS(RADIANS(-19.943379)) *
        COS(RADIANS('lat')) *
        COS(RADIANS('long') - RADIANS(-43.9521885)) +
        SIN(RADIANS(-19.943379)) *
        SIN(RADIANS('lat'))
    )) AS distance
FROM
    wppl_friends_locator
HAVING
    distance < 30
ORDER BY
    distance;
```

so even if i do an entry in this table with same lat long which I am providing in sql query, It still does not return any results.

I have been stuck on it for few days, any help would be appreciated.

Table structure
[image: Table structure]

Comment: would you please provide some sample data; include some that you expect the query to return within the distance < 30 (private data is not needed)

Comment: `'lat'` and `'long'` are strings, not column names. change them to just `lat` and `long`.

Comment: Or use backtics `\`lat\``

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When to use single quotes, double quotes, and back ticks in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-back-ticks-in-mysql)

Comment: Thank You Nick and Rick, Thank You everyone finally the query worked.

this returned results.


SELECT member_id, (3959 * ACOS( COS(RADIANS(-19.943379)) * COS(RADIANS(`lat`)) * COS(RADIANS(`long`) - RADIANS(-43.9521885)) + SIN(RADIANS(-19.943379)) * SIN(RADIANS(`lat`)) )) AS distance FROM wppl_friends_locator HAVING distance < 30 ORDER BY distance

Thank You Guys for Help!